# how to access contents of a text box using name of the input text box element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
  function display() {
    var x = document.nid.value;
    //document.body.innerHTML=x;
    document.write(x);
  }
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Print Reverse of a number</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Enter number
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" size="20" name="nid">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="display()">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('nid')[0].value`

Comment: the name attribute is very different to the id attribute, especially with input elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your should replace

```
var x = document.nid.value
```

By

```
x = document.getElementsByName("nid")[0].value;
```

Comment: If I enclose the entire input textbox inside form element using <form> tag ,and I access it using document.form.nid.value where nid is the name of the textbox , then it works ,but If I use document.body.nid.value where the input textbox is enclosed inside the body tag using <body> , then it doesn't work .why is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourinputs = document.getElementByName("nid")
```

this will return an array of elements. Since you need the first one, you can choose the `0th` element of array

```
var input_val = yourinputs[0].value;
```

or simply in one line as

```
var input_val = document.getElementByName("nid")[0].value;
```

Comment: If I enclose the entire input textbox inside form element using <form> tag ,and I access it using document.form.nid.value where nid is the name of the textbox , then it works ,but If I use document.body.nid.value where the input textbox is enclosed inside the body tag using <body> , then it doesn't work .why is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementsByName(name)` to select all nodes by name. It will return an array, take the node for which you want to retrieve value and use `value` method.

```js
function logValue() {
  console.log(document.getElementsByName("nid")[0].value);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" size="20" name="nid" onchange="logValue()">
```

Answer (score 0):

var inputField=document.getElementsByName('nid');

This Will return you array of 0th element, then you can get the value

var inputValue=inputField[0].value;

(**Or you can directly make it in a single variable**)

var inputFieldValue=document.getElementsByName('nid')[0].value;

Comment: If I enclose the entire input textbox inside form element using <form> tag ,and I access it using document.form.nid.value where nid is the name of the textbox , then it works ,but If I use document.body.nid.value where the input textbox is enclosed inside the body tag using <body> , then it doesn't work .why is it so ?

Comment: [ Check the following link ] (https://plnkr.co/edit/g8cYBnw7BWPtVflA312e?p=preview)  Use this Line to get the value from input field

 var a= document.body.children.yourtextboxname.value;

Comment: I got your point , just wanted to ask does it take the empty line as a child node in the body tag ,like <body>                         hiii</body> so here whitespace mentioned after body tag ,is it also considered as a child node ?

Comment: No it wont take it as child , unless u mention it inside any html element like(<p>,<input> etc)